# Why won't my OpenGL texture display correctly?

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm using GLFW and GLEW to initialize a window, and SOIL to load image data for a texture. I'm trying (and failing) to load a texture to display on a simple square in the middle of the screen.
Here's the code:

```
GLuint VAO, VBO, EBO, texture, shaderProgram;
GLFWWindow* window;
const char* vertexShaderSource = //Shown later
const char* fragmentShaderSource = //Shown later

void init()
{
  glfwInit();

  window = glfwCreateWindow(320, 288, "GameBozo", nullptr, nullptr);
  glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

  glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
  glewInit()

  glViewport(0, 0, 320, 288);

  GLfloat vertices[] = {
    // Positions          // Colors           // Texture Coords
     0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f, // Top Right
     0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f, // Bottom Right
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f, // Bottom Left
    -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f  // Top Left 
  };
  GLuint indices[] = {
    0, 1, 3, // First Triangle
    1, 2, 3  // Second Triangle
  };

  //Generate vertex arrays and buffers
  glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
  glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
  glGenBuffers(1, &EBO);

  glBindVertexArray(VAO);

  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
  glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

  glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
  glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

  //Shaders
  GLuint vertexShader;
  vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
  glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexShaderSource, NULL);
  glCompileShader(vertexShader);
  GLuint fragmentShader;
  fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
  glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentShaderSource, NULL);
  glCompileShader(fragmentShader);
  shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
  glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
  glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
  glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);

  // Position attribute
  glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)0);
  glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
  // Color attribute
  glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)(3 * sizeof(GLfloat)));
  glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
  // TexCoord attribute
  glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)(6 * sizeof(GLfloat)));
  glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);



// Load and create a texture 
  glGenTextures(1, &texture);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

  int width, height;
  GLubyte* image = SOIL_load_image("path\to\image.jpg", &width, &height, 0, SOIL_LOAD_RGB);
  glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
  glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
  SOIL_free_image_data(image);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
}
```

And then the main loop:

```
void main()
{
glfwPollEvents();

glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
glBindVertexArray(VAO);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
glBindVertexArray(0);

glfwSwapBuffers(window);
}
```

And finally, the vertex shader:

```
#version 330
layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 color;
layout (location = 2) in vec2 texCoord;

out vec3 ourColor;
out vec2 TexCoord;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0f);
    ourColor = color;
    TexCoord = texCoord;
}
```

And the fragment shader:

```
#version 330
in vec3 ourColor;
in vec2 TexCoord;

out vec4 color;

uniform sampler2D ourTexture;

void main()
{
    color = texture(ourTexture, TexCoord) * vec4(ourColor, 1.0);
}
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong... the square will just show up white.

Comment: Is this the complete shader code? You will need a `#version ...` at the start. The default is version `110`, and your shader code would not be valid in that version.

Comment: Yeah, it's #version 330. My bad, will add it soon.

Comment: To narrow down the problem, I would try using the texture coordinates as the color. For example, use `color = vec4(TexCoord, 0.0, 1.0);` in the fragment shader. You should get a nice gradient with red and green across your quad.

Comment: Is `"path\to\image.jpg"` actually similar to what you are really using? If so, you are forgetting about the standard [escape sequences](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape) for string literals in C/C++.  You probably want to use `\\ `, or simply `/` which works on most platforms - including windows.

Comment: Yeah, I use the double backslash.